# Win Key + # beyond 9?

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-shortcuts, taskbar

If I press the Win Key + a number I can switch to or open the program pinned to the task bar.  This works up to 9.  If I want to get beyond 9, and into the double digits what do I press?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

According to [Microsoft Support](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/keyboard-shortcuts), it seems 10 (0) is the highest you can get:

> <kbd>Windows logo</kbd> + <kbd>number</kbd>
>
> Start the program pinned to the taskbar in the position indicated by the number. If the program is already running, switch to that program.

Another trick you could try is:

> <kbd>Windows logo</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>
>
> Cycle through programs on the taskbar with the arrow keys.

Comment: Acually 0 works for the tenth.

Comment: Win+T actually also puts focus on the taskbar. You can then use the left and right arrow or the Home and End keys to select a pinned item. The item can then be activated with Enter.