# Make Win key + numpad numbers work

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-shortcuts, numpad

It's possible to use Win Key + a number to switch between pinned programs as described in [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/595842/win-key-beyond-9)

I find that it would be more convenient to use the numpad numbers, but it does not work. (tried switching with `num` key).

Is it possible on Windows 7?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end I could only remap them using AutoHotKey:

```
#Numpad1::
send, #1
Return

#Numpad2::
send, #2
Return
```

etc...